# How to import a google font as Open Type to use css font-feature-settings

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I am using the [Quicksand font from Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Quicksand?selection.family=Quicksand:300,400,500,700).

I want to use CSS `font-feature-settings` but the font does not seem to support this in the format it is imported as from Google fonts.

From what I have read it seems that only fonts in `OpenType` format support `font-feature-settings`.

Is there a way to import this font in a format that supports `font-feature-settings`?

Comment: It looks like the only available file type for the font is .ttf, so you are probably out of luck. TTF files simply don't contain that kind of information.

Comment: You can download an OTF file from [the author's website](http://www.andrewpaglinawan.com/typeface/), but that seems to be an older version (from 2012). Also, if the OTF was created from a TTF, it may not contain the features you want either.

Comment: Truetype font _are_ OpenTyphe fonts. [OpenType is the container and data organisation specification](http://pomax.github.io/CFF-glyphlet-fonts/), the ttf/otf extensions are historical artifacts that serve literally no purpose other than to allow ancient font engines to load fonts based on extension. No modern engine does. `ttf` are "OpenType with truetype glyph data" and `otf` are "OpenType with CFF or CFF2 data". Anything OpenType related applies to both (_and_ the OpenType with embedded bitmaps, _and_ OpenType with embedded SVG).

Comment: In fact, don't use `ttf` or `otf` _at all_ if your target is the web. Use the woff2 (or older woff) versions. Which are still OpenType fonts, but with individual data tables compressed, and certain "necessary for universal font, meaningless for web deployment" data tables removed.

Comment: @Mike I assumed that since ttf is an older standard, .ttf files do not contain the newer features. Otherwise, why have the different extensions?

Comment: You assumed entirely incorrectly. As for the "why": because of historical reasons, and "breaking all the old tech that billions of dollars of production work rely on" is not a very compelling reason to rename files. Unless you've learned about modern font engineering, and know why some font might not be: pretty much every normal font you use today is an OpenType font. The main differentiator is which data table formats are used internally to encode glyph outlines, but everything else is the same, including OpenType features.